# Funnel Setup in Google Analytic through Virtual pageview tag in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need help in creating a Goal with funnel into a Google Analytics for New Registrations using virtual pageview tag on GTM.

I am not sure what trigger should be use for this tag? Tag is here:

[image]

Can anyone help/guide me to setup a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to push your own custom event on the dataLayer every time a "virtual" page is shown. You could do this as follows:

`dataLayer.push({'event' : 'virtualPageview', 'virtualPageName' : 'virtual/registration/complete'});`

You would then create a GTM trigger of type Custom Event and the name of the event would be `virtualPageview`. This will cause your Google Analytics page view tracking tag to fire every time a virtual page is shown. You would also need to pass the value of the `virtualName` dataLayer key to the GA page view tag. You can do this using the "Fields to Set" section of the tag configuration as follows:
[image: Tag Configuration in GTM]. The `Virtual Page Name` variable would be defined as follows:[image: Virtual Page Name variable configuration]

Then, when defining your goal funnel in Google Analytics, you would enter `some/virtual/page/name` as the funnel step as follows:[image: Funnel configuration in GA]

Comment: VirtualPageview tags are firing correctly. I have pushed following datalayer:

dataLayer.push({
'event':'VirtualPageview',
'virtualPageURL':'/virtual/login/',
'virtualPageTitle' : ' Registration Page'
});

But now the problem is: Google Analytic funnel is not showing any results. oi63.tinypic.com/2coqzxx.jpg 

Funnel Setup is here: oi65.tinypic.com/21e9rwp.jpg.

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you describe what the actual steps of the funnel are? You expect a user to first visit the login page (which is a virtual page) and then complete a registration? If so, what page is the user sent to after a registration is complete?

Comment: Exactly, I am expecting users to visit the login page,where they will complete the registration process. But don't want to send them any other page instead they will see a pop with Registration Successful notification and redirected to same page. 

Can I see results like this?: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2vam9lu.jpg,

Virtualpageview tag is working through GTM

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do same as per your steps and screenshots and then share feedback with you.

Comment: Again, while debugging tags are firing correctly. But analytic is not counting virtual page views. See here http://oi67.tinypic.com/2ngg0wh.jpg. 

Is the popup after successful registration stop tracking page views? 

This is the url: zapkam dot com/login/

Comment: Can you please show me screenshots of your goal configuration in GA.

Comment: Here is the goal configuration: http://oi66.tinypic.com/2vuj0bo.jpg. Following is the datalayer I have pushed: 

window.dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'virtualPageview', 
    'virtualPageName' : 'virtual/registration/complete'});

Real time conversions are also not showing in the analytics when I am debugging tags.

Comment: Are you sure you're pushing `'virtualPageURL' : 'virtual/registration/complete'` onto the dataLayer? If so, did you make sure to add an extra trigger to your GA page view tag in GTM so that the tag fires when you push the `virtualPageview` event onto the dataLayer? From what I can tell from your funnel visualization report screenshot, the virtual page view is not firing.

Comment: Yes, I am pushing 'virtualPageURL' : 'virtual/registration/complete' into datalayer. 

Didn't understand statement: make sure to add an extra trigger to your GA page view tag in GTM. 

If tags virtual page view tag is not firing then it will definitely not shown while debugging.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the virtual page tag firing?